# <video> fullscreen expands document, not element itself — why?

Tags: javascript, html, video, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I want the user to be able to use the native `<video>` controls of a `<video>` [on this page/overlay](http://ohapostrophe.com.s154569.gridserver.com/projects/using-big-data-at-stanford-medicine), but right now the fullscreen action expands the whole website document rather than the video element itself, which isn't showing the overlay and its video at all.

Why isn't the `<video>` element full-screen'd by itself, natively in browsers?

Can I override the default behavior and use [requestFullscreen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried. Or a link the the website?

Comment: @KevinJantzer added a link in the description text, thanks for fast reply. click the fullscreen button after playing the video in the black overlay

Comment: – I don't see a fullscreen button: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/7qPNfcG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're calling `requestFullscreen()` from the window (the default if you call the method on its own)

You can also call it from a specific element, such as your video element.

```js
document.getElementById('video').requestFullscreen()
```

## [Demo](http://codepen.io/kjantzer/pen/BzJpgB)